# oracle health check report last_call

Tags: oracle

```
************************
Long running sessions  for LNLS12P_SB
************************

INST_ID     SID SERIAL# SQL_ID        USERNAME               LOCKWAIT         SCHEMANAME    MACHINE     LAST_CALL
------- ------- ------- ------------- ------------------------------ ---------------- ---------------    --------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------
      1     166   56286 fxd3d1mf6qsg4 NPL_USER                        NPL_USER                 nycindapp4.us.db.com                398.57
      1     848   57444 fxd3d1mf6qsg4 NPL_USER                        NPL_USER                nycindapp4.us.db.com                 408.53
      1     273   15473 fxd3d1mf6qsg4 NPL_USER                        NPL_USER          nycindapp3.us.db.com                   418.53
      1     844   58591 fxd3d1mf6qsg4 NPL_USER                        NPL_USER          nycindapp3.us.db.com                   428.58
      1     139   45028 fxd3d1mf6qsg4 NPL_USER                        NPL_USER              nycindapp3.us.db.com                   512.73
      1     718   18749 fxd3d1mf6qsg4 NPL_USER                        NPL_USER         nycindapp3.us.db.com                522.75
```

I am troubleshooting a database performance issue. In the report I spot a few long running sessions.  Not sure what last_call exactly stands for..

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the `LAST_CALL` column refers to `V$SESSION.LAST_CALL_ET`, which the [19c Database Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SESSION.html) describes as:

> If the session STATUS is currently ACTIVE, then the value represents
> the elapsed time (in seconds) since the session has become active.
>
> If the session STATUS is currently INACTIVE, then the value represents
> the elapsed time (in seconds) since the session has become inactive.

To know for sure, it would help if you specified exactly what Oracle health check you are using. If necessary, you could probably figure out how the health check is working by running this query while the health check results are being generated: `select * from gv$sql where users_executing > 0;`